# Swift 4- How to implement swiping between UIViews to recreate Spotify song selection

Tags: swift, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am attempting to mimic the feature found in Spotify that allows one to swipe between UIViews. As of now, I have created a UIView class, but do not know how to implement fluid movement between them or how to draw the other UIViews, since they'll have to be partially off-screen for some time. As reference, this is what I am attempting to mimic. [Example of Spotify swipeability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIigc.gif)

Comment: iCarousel, UICollectionView with custom CollectionViewFlowLayout, etc.

Comment: This should help you get started. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview Also there are many youtube videos that cover collection views. If you're a novice try to get a thorough understanding of whats happening data wise before you delve into custom layouts. Best of luck.